# JavaScript for table row onclick is working fine with IE but not with Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have gone through all the related questions and their answers in the forum, but could not find any help. My JavaScript for Java form submit is working fine with IE but not with Firefox. My sample code is this.

```
function redirect(elem){
        
    var m = elem.rowIndex;       
    var row=0;
    row = tableId.rows[m];
    var var1 = row.cells(2).value;    
    var var2 = row.cells(0).value;  
    document.formName.action="some.do?var1 ="+var1 +"&var2="+var2 ;
        
    document.formName.submit();
        
}
```

Please, I need help.

Comment: Could you explain what happens in FireFox? Do you get any errors in th e console?

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are wrong, You may got script errors.So the form is not submited.

```
var var1 = row.cells(2).value; 
var var2 = row.cells(0).value;
```

use below statements to get column values

```
 var var1 = row.cells[2].innerText;
 var var2 = row.cells[0].innerText;
```